# Count on GROUP BY and also on total number of results

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, count

I have three tables:

`users` which have just two columns: `id: INT, name: TEXT`

`houses` which have three columns: `id: INT, user_id: INT, sold_at: DATE`

`users_with_house_permissions` which have two columns: `id: INT, user_id: INT`

I have this query that founds the number of houses sold by a user (as long as it has house_permissions):

```
SELECT users.id as user_id, COUNT(*) as houses_sold
FROM users
JOIN users_with_house_permissions hp ON hp.user_id = users.id
LEFT JOIN houses on houses.user_id = users.id AND houses.sold_at IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY users.id
```

Now, how can I get the total number of rows that this return? I am trying to do pagination and I need to know the total number of rows that this query will return.

So for example, if I have the following content:

```
users (id, name):

1, John
2, Carla
3, Bula

users_with_house_permissions (id, user_id):

1, 1
2, 2

houses (id, user_id, sold_at):

1, 1, '2018-10-10'
```

I would like the result of the query to be:

```
user_id: 1
houses_sold: 1
total_count: 2

user_id: 2
houses_sold: 0
total_count: 2
```

So, total_count would represent the number of rows that this query will return.

Comment: Sorry, forgot the tag, it's postgresql

Comment: I don't understand why the `total_count` is 2 for both users.  Can you explain this to us?

Comment: Yes, that would be the number of rows that the query returns. Since there are two users with house permissions that we want to get the total number of houses sold, then it's two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an analytic/window function count without any partition:

```
SELECT users.id as user_id, COUNT(*) as houses_sold,

  COUNT(*) OVER() as total_count -- count of rows returned by query

FROM users
JOIN users_with_house_permissions hp ON hp.user_id = users.id
LEFT JOIN houses on houses.user_id = users.id AND houses.sold_at IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY users.id
```

It works like any other analytic function; it counts over a partition, but if there is no partition specified, then it counts over the entire dataset. In this case the countover is done after the grouping is done, so while `count(*)` counts the number of items in the group, `count(*) over()` counts the number of groups in the data set

Someone else posted a `sum(count(*)) over()` which is the effective equivalent of counting the rows before they are grouped. If you had a data set of "who sold the house" and it went thus:

```
john
john
john
mary
```

4 houses have been sold, john sold 3, mary sold 1. There are 2 sales reps working for the agency.

`COUNT(*) FROM ... GROUP BY name` gives the "john sold 3, mary sold 1" and results in a dataset of:

```
john, 3
mary, 1
```

If we were to SUM that count, we'd have 4, i.e. 3+1. This is effectively the count of houses before the grouping was done. `SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER()` is hence the count of rows we had before we did the group. It's important to bear in mind that the COUNT(*) belongs to the GROUP BY and will become an integer count that is then later SUMmed by the SUM OVER. It would probably be easier to see if we used a subquery:

```
SELECT name, the_count, SUM(the_count) OVER()
FROM (SELECT name, count(*) as the_count FROM sales GROUP BY name) subquery
```

But because analytics are calculated after grouping is done, there isn't really any need to present it like this; the db would do this in the same way as it would do:

```
SELECT name, count(*), sum(count(*)) over() FROM sales GROUP BY name
```

Thus we get to the point where you appreciate that analytics are applied after a grouping is performed, it means that where `COUNT(*) OVER()` is a count of the number of rows in the dataset after the grouping operation is finished. The grouping produced `john,3|mary,1` so COUNT(*) OVER() this produces 2 - the number of rows in the dataset

The documentation, if you want to read more, is titled "Windows Functions" and can be found somewhere like here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/tutorial-window.html

This is for PG 9.1; remember to change the view to your specific version of PG

Comment: This is great. How does this work? I can't find the docs in Postgresql

Comment: Added a note to explain

Answer (score 1):

You can try below - scalar subquery

```
SELECT users.id as user_id, COUNT(*) as houses_sold,(select count(*) from users_with_house_permissions a) as totalcount
FROM users
JOIN users_with_house_permissions hp ON hp.user_id = users.id
LEFT JOIN houses on houses.user_id = users.id AND houses.sold_at IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY users.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want:

```
select uhp.user_id, count(h.id) as houses_sold,
       sum(count(h.id)) over () as total_count
from users_with_house_permissions left join
     houses h
     on h.user_id = uhp.user_id
group by uhp.user_id;
```

You don't appear to need the `users` table, because you only want users in `users_with_house_permissions`.

The `count()` counts the number of matching rows, so you can get the rows with a `0` count.  The window function then gets the total over all rows.